# Get full join in google big query keeping the all frequecy combination in bigquery giving me only left join for all kind of join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I am trying to join 2 table using Id such that the frequency of all combination  are present. But when I am using the join (left, right) I am still getting the inner join or left join output.

these are the table a

[image]

b 
[image]

I am expecting output

[image]

I tried the actual code

```
select 
    act.action, 
    dvr.dateofdel, 
    dvr.output   
FROM internal.actions as act 
Right join internal.deliveries as dvr 
    ON dvr.id= act.id
```

I tried multiple joins but still same outcome ..

Comment: please formulate your requirements using those same names from "simplified" example OR adjust your examples to have same names as in query - but still explain the logic of the joining you want to achieve. "Forcing" us to do wild guessing (like in below answer) is just wasting of our and your own time o(

Comment: still total mess! can you explain in plain English the logic you are trying to implement!? meantime, voting to close till more details provided

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: When clear this will be a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not match your sample data.

But based on your problem statement, I suspect that you want:

```
select 
    act.ID_log, 
    act.ID_send_message, 
    act.action_date, 
    act.action,act.ID_email, 
    dvr.delivery_date, 
    act.email   
from internal.actions as act 
left join internal.deliveries as dvr 
    on  dvr.ID_send_message= act.ID_send_message  
    and dvr.delivery_date >= '2017-01-01'
    and dvr.delivery_date <  '2018-01-01'
where act.ID_send_message != 0
```

This will bring all records from `act` that satisfy the condition in the `where` clause, along with information coming from `dvr`; when there is no match in `dvr`, the corresponding columns will show `null` values. The important part in the query is that all conditions on the `left join`ed table should be listed in the `on` clause of the `join` (rather than in the `where` clause).

Comment: yes .. The names were too odd so I represented the requirement in simple names to explain better.

Comment: @SouravRoy: does the query produce the expected results?

Comment: no its joining the left columns whereever its matching , if someone is present in column 2 but not in column 1 then its not showing up